# In .NET, is finally equivalent to try-catch-throw?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

I am writing a static analysis tool for CIL. Control flow analysis would be simplified if finally blocks could be interpreted as try-catch blocks with a rethrow inside the catch.
In C#, I fail to see the difference between

```
try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    // finally code here
}
```

and

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch
{
    // finally code here
    throw;
}
```

or between

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    // catch code here
}
finally
{
    // finally code here
}
```

and

```
try
{
    try
    {
        // ...
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // catch code here
    }
}
catch
{
    // finally code here
    throw;
}
```

There are even a finally block and endfinally instructions in the CIL. There must be a difference, is there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No - a `finally` block is executed even if no exception is thrown, and *also* even if another `catch` block catches the exception. (That's true whether the `catch` block then throws an exception itself or not.)

Oh, and a `finally` block will *also* be executed if the `try` block returns from the method.

Basically, if you want code to always execute when execution leaves the statement, `finally` is what you want. Although in C# I find I rarely write an explicit `finally` block - a `using` statement nearly always makes the code simpler.

Answer (score 14):

To add to Jon's -- correct, of course -- answer: you are actually describing a `try-fault` block. That is, a `try-fault` block is equivalent to `try` followed by `catch`-everything and automatic re-`throw`.

C# does not support `try-fault` blocks but CIL does, so if you're ever reading IL and you see a `fault` block, now you know what it is.

Also, it *is* correct to say that

```
try{} 
catch {} 
finally {}
```

is equivalent to

```
try 
{ 
    try { } 
    catch { } 
} 
finally { }
```

And in fact inside the C# compiler that's what it does; all try-catch-finally blocks are rewritten into a nested try-catch inside a try-finally. That is a simplifying assumption that can help when writing a static analyzer.